# laravel multiple upload getClientOriginalName on array

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

hello im trying to upload multiple file on laravel. im following my others single upload file laravel. but when im trying to submit, it says an error

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

i know the problem, but i dont know how to solved it.
here's my blade view

```
<div class="row pb-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><label>Akta Lain Lain </label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="custom-file" style="width: 500px; height: 40px; cursor: pointer;">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="ALL[]" multiple>
            <label class="custom-file-label">Choose file</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my controller

```
$deb = new Debitur_Badan_Usaha();
     if ($request->hasFile('ALL')) {
        $files = [];
           foreach ($request->file('ALL') as $items) {
              if ($items->isValid()) {
                $name_all = time().'_'.rand(1,9999).'_'.$request->ALL->getClientOriginalName();
                $items->move('data_debitur/', $name_all);
                $files [] = $name_all;
               }
            }
                $deb->AKTE_LAIN_LAIN = $files;
                $deb->save();
      }
```

i think the problem bcs on the name blade file is ALL[] but the getclientoriginalname doesnt accept an array? does anyone know how to solved it so it can be uploading multiple image? thank u

**updated controller**

```
$deb = new Debitur_Badan_Usaha();

if ($request->hasFile('ALL')) {
    $files = [];
    foreach ($request->ALL as $file) {
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            $name_all = time().'_'.rand(1,9999).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('data_debitur/', $name_all);
            array_push($files, $name_all);
        }
    }
    $deb->AKTE_LAIN_LAIN = $files;
    $deb->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, you already have a foreach loop to deal with the array of files, all you need to do is to now utilize it and use it, here is how:

**Note:** I changed items -> file, then for getting the original name, you can call that directly on the file.

```
if ($request->hasFile('ALL')) {

    //foreach file request
    foreach($request->ALL as $file) {
        if ($file->isValid()) {
            //here we will call the file originalname
            $name_all = time().'_'.rand(1,9999).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            //moving the file
            $file->move('data_debitur/', $name_all);

            //we add the file to the field and save it
            $deb->AKTE_LAIN_LAIN = $name_all;
            $deb->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Extra:** you can also get the extension like `$file->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: umm hello thanks for the answer, i tried ur answer but it causes another error, the error says `Array to string conversion`

Comment: @zeinmu can you be more specific, which method or line is throwing the error? also, check my modified answer.

Comment: sorry the error doesnt shows the line or method that i code. the error exception only says Array to string conversion

Comment: @zeinmu check now the updated if statement :) i noticed late that the array was also wrong

Comment: still have the same error... `Array to string conversion`

Comment: you can check my updated controller :) in case i wrote the code wrong :)

Comment: @zeinmu sorry for the late reply, your error was because the  `$deb->AKTE_LAIN_LAIN = $files;` was outside of the foreach loop, please check my answer again, i fixed it for you :)

Comment: so we dont use the $files [] to save the images/files?

Comment: @zeinmu depends, how you want to store the **$deb->AKTE_LAIN_LAIN** as an array or a single file? in your database

Comment: because the **$deb->AKTE_LAIN_LAIN** is a multiple upload, i think it'll store as an aray

Comment: Then you can do that directly with your updated controller, dont use my modified solution, it should work. Just make sure your table **AKTE_LAIN_LAIN** is a text or you can save as JSON, honestly up to you :)